# Since update to RestSharp v110 only 401 unauthorized errors

Tags: c#, authentication, basic-authentication, restsharp

We used RestSharp v107 without problems this way:

```
        RestClientOptions options = new RestClientOptions()
        {
            BaseUrl = new Uri(serviceUrl),
            PreAuthenticate = false,
            Timeout = cTimeout,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            UserAgent = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}/{FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).FileVersion}",
            Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
        };
        _restClient = new RestClient(options);

        RestRequest request = new RestRequest("instancetoken", Method.Post);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "text/plain");
        request.AddParameter(nameof(username), username);
        request.AddParameter(nameof(password), password);
        RestResponse response = await _restClient.ExecuteAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(true);
```

Now with v110 we had to change some things and tried it this way:

```
        RestClientOptions options = new RestClientOptions()
        {
            BaseUrl = new Uri(serviceUrl),
            Authenticator = string.IsNullOrEmpty(instanceToken) ? new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, password) : (IAuthenticator)new JwtAuthenticator(instanceToken),
            MaxTimeout = cTimeout,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            UserAgent = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}/{FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).FileVersion}",
            Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
        };
        _restClient = new RestClient(options);
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest("instancetoken", Method.Post);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "text/plain");
        RestResponse response = await _restClient.ExecuteAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(true);
```

So now the question: What are we doing wrong here? This way I only get 401 authentication failed errors.

---

Edit: Sorry forgot to mention one thing. I had used the setter of the instance token to set the authenticator of the jwt if needed. Now it is read only:

```
    private string _instanceToken = null;
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the current instance token.
    /// </summary>
    public string InstanceToken
    {
        get => _instanceToken;
        private set
        {
            if (_instanceToken != value)
            {
                _instanceToken = value;
                _restClient.Authenticator = string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? null : (IAuthenticator)new JwtAuthenticator(value);
                OnPropertyChanged("InstanceToken");
                OnPropertyChanged("IsConnected");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You weren't using the authenticator before, why do you need to use it now? The code you had for v107 should work exactly the same way with v110. You also should avoid setting the content type manually, it's mentioned in the docs several times.

Basic authenticator is not adding username and password parameters, it sets the auth header to the hex encoded value. https://restsharp.dev/authenticators.html

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev You are right, but sadly I forgot to mention one important thing. I edited my question accordingly. Btw. sorry for taking so long to answer, laid down sick...

Comment: And depending the content... that would be right if the server would work as expected... let it be... do not want to argue with my colleague ;)

Comment: The `HttpBasicAuthenticator` work by encoding the pair `username:password` to hex64 and setting it as the auth header. It doesn't add parameters to the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments and updated question, I think this would work. I might still misunderstand the case, but still:

```
RestClientOptions options = new RestClientOptions()
{
    BaseUrl = new Uri(serviceUrl),
    Authenticator = string.IsNullOrEmpty(instanceToken) ? null : new JwtAuthenticator(instanceToken),
    MaxTimeout = cTimeout,
    UserAgent = userAgent,
};
_restClient = new RestClient(options);
var request = new RestRequest("instancetoken", Method.Post);
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(instanceToken))
{
    request
        .AddParameter(nameof(username), username)
        .AddParameter(nameof(password), password);
}
var response = await _restClient.ExecuteAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(true);
```

It won't set the authenticator if there's no token supplied, and add two parameters for the form. I removed the code that sets the `Content-Type` (POST calls are by default using url-encoded form) and `Accept` headers as they are set by default anyway.